# The script does not end when you press enter

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want catch a value of text area when I press enter. The problem is the script execution no finalize and I'cant see the result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).on("ready",function() {
        $("#buscador_texto").keypress(function (event) {


            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

            //alert (keycode);

            if(keycode=="13") {

                //$("#tabla_usuario_individual").show();
                var cod = $('#buscador_texto').val();
                alert (cod);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo site_url("archivo/prueba"); ?>',
                   // data: {'cod':cod}, //enviamos el código por POST

                    success: function(resp) {

                        $("#tabla_usuario_individual").html(resp);


                    }
                });


            };


        });

    });


</script>
```

Comment: Watch the request in your browser developer tools (f12). Do you see any errors? What does the response look like in the network tab of the tools? You have the data commented out, does your php file expect data?

Comment: There is no execution problem, but the result 
The result appears and disappears because the script continues outside if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `$(document).ready` , not  `$(document).on("ready")`. 'ready' event is a jquery specific event that can only be binded , not delegated.

Working Example : https://jsfiddle.net/7a86nfwq/1/

Comment: the problem persists, performs the action but immediately afterwards run again without going through the "if"

Comment: make sure you do not have any other event binded to the input 'buscador_texto'

Answer (score 0):

Use **$(document).ready(function(){** instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buscador_texto").keypress(function (event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode=="13") {

            //$("#tabla_usuario_individual").show();
            var cod = $('#buscador_texto').val();
            alert (cod);
        };
    });

});
```

You can check https://jsfiddle.net/xupat5q5/